# Python CLI application does not run when installed from PyPI, runs fine when installed locally

Tags: python, installation, pip, pypi

Say I'm working on a command line application called Example, where its invocation command is `example`. I wrote a setup.py that looks like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='example',
    version='1.0',
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'example=example.run:main'
        ]
    },
    ...
)
```

This file is placed at the same level as a module called `example` (with its `__init__.py` and all. There is a `run.py` inside it, with a `main` function.

When I install this work-in-progress project as a symlink using...

```
pip3 install -e .
```

... it works fine. I am able to run it from anywhere using the `example` command.

But when I follow [these instructions](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to upload it to PyPI, then install it using...

```
pip3 install example
```

... it says...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/example", line 7, in <module>
    from example.run import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

Of course the project is not actually called `example`; there's nothing conflicting with its name.

Comment: That is not a complete error traceback -- you left out the actual error message.

Comment: Whoops! Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install a module `example` from file `example.py` you
need to add it as a Python module to `setup.py`:

```
setuptools.setup(
    …
    py_modules=['example'],
    …
)
```

If `example` is a package from directory `example/` you
need to add it as a package:

```
setuptools.setup(
    …
    packages=['example'],
    …
)
```

If `example` has subpackages from `example/*/` subdirectories you
need to list all subpackages:

```
setuptools.setup(
    …
    packages=['example', 'example.sub1', 'example.sub2'],
    …
)
```

You can make `setuptools` to list all subpackages for your:

```
setuptools.setup(
    …
    packages=setuptools.find_packages()
    …
)
```